# Deploying PostSharp into a Source Repository with NuGet Package Restore

Tags: nuget, postsharp

Is it possible to Deploy PostSharp into a Source Repository in conjunction with NuGet Package Restore?
I can get this working by committing the postsharp package, but that negates somewhat the value of the Package Restore feature.

**Here’s what I did.**

- I was trying to set up postshap like so: [Deploying post sharp into a source repo](http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/41129237-a5d4-4acf-aef4-c46759ccfb4b.htm)
- I have set up nugget to use without commiting like so: [Using NuGet Without Committing Packages to Source Control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages#Setup)

I see this in my csproj

```
<Import Project="..\packages\PostSharp.2.1.6.13\tools\PostSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
```

(I re-ordered them to no avail)

And my build server (CC.net) reports the following errors:

```
D:\wwwroot\www.snip.co.nz\http\www.snip.co.nz.csproj (714,3):

errorMSB4019: The imported project     "D:\wwwroot\www.snip.co.nz\packages\PostSharp.2.1.6.13\tools\PostSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the &lt;Import&gt; declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

CacheAttribute.cs (8,7):
errorCS0246: The type or namespace name 'PostSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
…etc…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently (v2.1.6.13) have to fix the csproj to support Package Restore,
within the Import target element add the condition shown here:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\PostSharp.2.1.6.13\tools\PostSharp.targets"  
     Condition="Exists('..\packages\PostSharp.2.1.6.13\tools\PostSharp.targets')" />
```